# unity fps jump with character controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, controls, frame-rate

I'm pretty new to unity and wanted to create a fps movement.
I found this tutorial from Brackeys and it works relatively well but if you jump with a ceiling over your head you're flying a few moments. I'm very sorry to ask such a basic question but I couldn't find anything. Here some code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController controller;
    Animator animator;

    public float speed = 7f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (x != 0)
        {
            animator.SetBool("WalkXTrigger", true);
            x /= 2;
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("WalkXTrigger", false);
        }

        if (z != 0)
        {
            if (z<0)
            {
                animator.SetBool("WalkBackTrigger", true);
                z /= 1.5f;
            }
            if (z>0)
            {
                animator.SetBool("WalkTrigger", true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("WalkTrigger", false);
            animator.SetBool("WalkBackTrigger", false);
        }

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2 * gravity);
            animator.SetBool("JumpTrigger", true);
        }

        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("JumpTrigger", false);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

So I think there are 2 options:
1. move the character down when he hits the ceiling
2. measure the space between character and ceiling and set it equal to the jump height
My Problem: I don't know how to do any of this
Hope my English is okay and the problem is described enough
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure whether your character keeps flying, or just stays there for a second or two, but either way, this little bit of code will work.

```
public GameObject ceiling; //set this to your ceiling in the editor.
public float ceilingDown = 0.5; //if this value doesn't work, just mess around with it a little.

void OnTriggerEnter(ceiling){
    velocity.y -= ceilingDown;
}
```

If you add this to your code, it should force the player downward slightly. Gravity will take over after this.

Comment: @affederaffe mark the answer as completed if you could :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why, but here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

public CharacterController controller;

public float speed = 12f;
public float speedy;
public float speedOffset = 3f;
public float gravity = -9.81f;
public float jumpHeight = 3f;

public float playerHeight = 1.6f;
public float groundDistance = 0.4f;


Vector3 velocity;
bool isGrounded;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray downRay = new Ray(transform.position, -Vector3.up);

    if (Physics.Raycast(downRay, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.distance >= playerHeight + groundDistance)
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }

            
    }
    
    
    if (isGrounded)
    {
        speedy = speed/(1 + speedOffset);
    }
    else
    {
        speedy = speed;
    }
    
    if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
    {
        velocity.y = -2f;
    }
    
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    
    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
    
    controller.Move(move * speedy * Time.deltaTime);
    
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
    }
    
    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I don't know, I'm an inexperienced 9 year old, so try this one to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

You have this at the end of your update loop so I'm assuming your character is always flying?

```
velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
```

Keep on coding and practicing and you will figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but this code simply works for character controllers. If you are not grounded (in the air) it checks to see if you collided with something above you. If you have, it flops your y velocity so that you come down immediately. Think of it like you bumped your head.

```
>         if (!isGrounded && (controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Above) != 0)
>         {
>             velocity.y = -velocity.y;
>         }
```